# Is there any way to use MathJax v3 in React?

Tags: reactjs, mathjax

`react-mathjax` uses version 2 and I am restricted to use version 3 + `Reactjs` for my project. Is there any library that can help me or must I do a whole rewrite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a package that I wrote: [better-react-mathjax](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-react-mathjax). It is highly configurable and allows using both version 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

The [mathjax-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mathjax-react) package is based on v3.